# Create Plan (BETA) doesn't seem to work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to create a planner plan using Graph as per http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_post_plans

but I'm consistently getting the following BadRequest response:

```
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Write requests are only supported on contained entities",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "eae08944-6f47-477e-9950-ade31c473dd7",
        "date": "2016-03-07T11:59:04"
    }
```

As per the docs I'm POSTing to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/plans with the following body:

```
"createdBy": "<my uuid>",
"owner": "<a previously generated group uuid>",
"title": "Blah Plan"
```

with no luck. The previously generated group looks like the following:

```
{
        "id": "<uuid>",
        "classification": null,
        "createdDateTime": "2016-03-07T09:53:26Z",
        "description": "Int Test",
        "displayName": "Int Test",
        "groupTypes": [
            "Unified"
        ],
        "mail": "<email_address>",
        "mailEnabled": true,
        "mailNickname": "IntTest",
        "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
        "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
        "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
        "proxyAddresses": [
            "SMTP:<email_address>"
        ],
        "renewedDateTime": "2016-03-07T09:53:26Z",
        "securityEnabled": false,
        "visibility": "Public"
    }
```

I've tried various combinations of request bodies. With and without createdBy values. With and without owner values. Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? The error is consistent across my integration tests as well as through the graph explorer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Sriram mentioned, this was a documentation bug. It has just been fixed. The updated URL is: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/plan_post_plans

The issue was in which endpoint to call to create a plan. **You should call "/plans" instead of "/me/plans".** You should also be aware that some of the data you are passing in is **read-only**. You should not include "createdBy" because this is a read-only property set by the service, not you. The [plan resource documentation](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/plan.htm) will show you all of the properties that can be set on a plan.

The last thing to keep in mind is that you can only have one plan per group. If you try to make a second plan, you'll receive an error about this from the API.

Comment: This is one mistake that one seems to do when they go with the flows of how other APIs are called like teams, chats, reports, workspaces....

Answer (score 1):

In Juli 2017 the API was modified and released. The new endpoint for [creating a plan](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/planner_post_plans) now is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans
```

with a request body e.g. like this:

```
{
  "owner": "<group-id>",
  "title": "my plan title"
}
```

where <group-id> must be the id of a previously created group.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the confusion here. The documentation has a bug will be updated shortly. To create a plan, please ensure that a group is created, and the user is member of group. Then create the plan with owner set to group id, and createdBy set to user id.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work either. I'm authenticated as my user. I have created the group using the api with me as an owner member (confirmed in the groups ui of outlook) and then attempted to create the plan using the group id as the owner value and my user id as the createdBy value. Still no dice.

On a related note. Adding tasks (using the api) to a previously created bucket also yields the same error. Using a planId and bucketId of a plan and bucket created using the planner UI at https://tasks.office.com

Comment: Could you share a request-id and timestamp for the POST /beta/plans request?

Comment: Sure.

"innerError": {
        "request-id": "eae08944-6f47-477e-9950-ade31c473dd7",
        "date": "2016-03-07T11:59:04"
    }

Comment: This problem stil exists few months latter.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, can you please try following the below steps exactly?

- Create a unified group
- Add user to be member of unified group
- Create plan by sending {“owner”: group-id, “title”: string} - do not send "createdBy" field since it's a read-only field

For adding tasks to buckets, it should work just fine if you sent

{“planId”: plan-id, “bucketId”: bucket-id, “title”: string}

If this still doesn't work, feel free to reach out to me at lixian@microsoft.com.

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: The remark about Richard does not improve the answer. Just stick to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.